# Changing behavior when radio is true (without changing the HTML structure)

Tags: css, sass

Friends I need to apply a style in (span class = "ui-radiobutton-icon") when the radio is true, can help me.
Grateful.

Restrictions: HTML structure

```
<div class="ui-radiobutton ui-widget">
   <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
       <input type="radio" name="groupname" value="Masculino" ng-reflect-checked="true">
   </div>
   <div ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" class="ui-radiobutton-box ui-widget ui-state-default ui-state-active">
       <span class="ui-radiobutton-icon fa fa-fw fa-circle" ng-reflect-klass="ui-radiobutton-icon" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]"></span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need a parent selector to do that, and as they don't exist (, and you can't change markup) a script will be needed. Why can't you change markup? ... You could move the actual input and use a label in its place, and doing that it can be done without script

Comment: The class "ui-radio button" could be the root ... it is a component of a third company I am customizing the interface

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample using your structure but with the radio moved to `ui-radiobutton`.

Will this work for you?

```css
input {
  display: none;
}
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid black;
}
input:checked ~ .ui-helper-hidden-accessible label {
  background: gray;
}
input:checked ~ .ui-radiobutton-box .ui-radiobutton-icon {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="ui-radiobutton">
  <input id="ui-radio-hidden" type="radio" name="uir">
  <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
    <label for="ui-radio-hidden"></label>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-radiobutton-box">
    <span class="ui-radiobutton-icon fa fa-fw fa-circle">Red when checked</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can not change the structure, see the component I am customize:
[www.primefaces.org](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/radiobutton)

Comment: @FellipeJ.deSousa Then script is your only option (as of today at least)